# Global variable + count number of times a function occurs

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have defined a global variable, `counter`, which should increment for every iteration of a while loop in a worker function being performed by threads in main. The worker procedure occurs when a global variable, `more`, is set to 1 and stops when "more" is set to 0.

However, the global variables do not seem to be changing as the while loop is not taking place. Please help me. I'm desperate at this stage!

Declaring the global variables outside main

```
    //Variable which controls whether worker procedure continues to perform and when it terminates
    int more;

    //Static variable to keep track of the number of transfers which have taken place 
    //while threads allow worker procedure to be performed
    int counter;
```

Setting up threads and worker procedure in main and changing values of more and counter

```
    //Create a thread handle to control threads
threadH[thread] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, worker, (LPVOID)thread, 0, NULL);
//Set number of transfers to zero
counter = 0;
    //Threads run until variable more is set to 0
more = 1;
    //Main thread sleeps for 10,000ms (10 seconds)
Sleep(1000);
//Set more = 0 so worker procedures being executed by threads terminate
more = 0;
    cout << "Counter = " << count << endl;
```

Worker procedure performed by threads
//Worker procedure

```
DWORD WINAPI worker(LPVOID thread)
{
    //Seed random number generator
    srand((int)thread);

    //Worker procedure continually transfers a random amount of money 
    //from one random account to another random account until the variable "more" is set to 1
    while (more == 1)
    {
            counter++;

        //InterlockedExchangeAdd((LONG*)&counter, 1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two problems: 1) more isn't set to 1 until after the threads are launched.  What if they already executed the while loop and executed nothing?  2) What is to say the threads are being launched within the 1 second sleep?  They probably are, but have you confirmed it?

Comment: Also, this code seems not to be the code you are actual using. Some definitions are missing. How is more declared?

Comment: [OT]:I don't think that `srand` is thread safe and do what you want...

Comment: If you have access to C++11, multi-threading is far easier to tackle!

Answer (score 0):

> u should declare the global variable as **volatile**

since it is **accessed by multiple threads** and any **optimization done by the compiler** may be leading to this.

```
volatile int count = 0;
```

Similalry for more.

```
volatile int more = 0;
```

Comment: volatile is not a solution for thread safety on multi-core. See for instance : http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming

Comment: `count` should be `std::atomic<int>`